# UITableView custom cells always change there content - must stop it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

i have a UITableView with custom cells (code below) that load the data from `NSDictionary` (the `NSDictionary` loads there data from NSArray `objectatIndexPath:indexpath.row`.

Now, i have a DidSelectRow functions that works in the same way (NSArray -> NSDictionary -> Cell data).

the problem is that when im scrolling my table its change my cells contant.
i must have my cells always reload that same order. and i must stop this reloading data when scrolling.

This is the code im using to load my table view and load data to table view cells and my didSelectRow: Please help, i dont have time for this problem...

```
        RequestArray = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"Content"];

        RequestTable =  [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 84, 320, 326)];
        RequestTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(234/255.f) green:(234/255.f) blue:(234/255.f) alpha:1];

        RequestTable.dataSource=self;
        RequestTable.delegate=self;

        RequestTable.rowHeight = 77;
        [self.view addSubview:RequestTable];

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: SimpleTableIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];

        NSDictionary *object = [RequestArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSString *Category = [object valueForKey:@"Category"];
        NSString *ItemDescription = [object valueForKey:@"ItemDescription"];
        NSString *ItemName = [object valueForKey:@"ItemName"];
        NSString *Date = [object valueForKey:@"Date"];
        NSString *ExpiresDate = [object valueForKey:@"ExpiresDate"];
        BOOL isRead = [[object valueForKey:@"IsRead"]boolValue];


        /// add time label to cell
        NSTimeInterval TIMEinterval = [Date intValue];
        NSDate* TIMEDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:TIMEinterval];
        NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
        [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:2]]; //+0000
        NSString* dateStrig = [df stringFromDate:TIMEDate];

        UILabel *RequestTime = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(268, 8, 33, 16)];
        [RequestTime setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
        RequestTime.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        RequestTime.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [RequestTime setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
        RequestTime.text = dateStrig;
        [cell addSubview:RequestTime];

        /// add experation label to cell

        NSTimeInterval EXPTIMEinterval = [ExpiresDate intValue];
        NSDate* EXPDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:EXPTIMEinterval];

        NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [EXPDate timeIntervalSinceDate:TIMEDate];
        int numberOfHours = secondsBetween / 3600;

        UILabel *ExperationTime = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(152, 24, 150, 15)];
        ExperationTime.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [ExperationTime setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
        ExperationTime.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(255/255.f) green:(103/255.f) blue:(18/255.f) alpha:1];
        [ExperationTime setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
        if (numberOfHours>24){
            numberOfHours = numberOfHours/24;
            ExperationTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"המוצר דרוש תוך %d ימים",numberOfHours];

        }else{
            ExperationTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"המוצר דרוש תוך %d שעות",numberOfHours];

        }
        [cell addSubview:ExperationTime];

        // add item category to cell

        UILabel *itamCategory = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(143 , 5, 120, 21)];
        itamCategory.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [itamCategory setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
        itamCategory.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(0/255.f) green:(177/255.f) blue:(233/255.f) alpha:1];
        [itamCategory setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17]];
        itamCategory.text = Category;
        [cell addSubview:itamCategory];

        // add item Name to cell

        UILabel *itamName = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(98, 39, 203, 21)];
        itamName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [itamName setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
        itamName.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [itamName setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17]];
        itamName.text = ItemName;
        [cell addSubview:itamName];

        // add item Description to cell

        UILabel *Description = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(98, 62, 203, 10)];
        Description.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [Description setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
        Description.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [Description setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13]];
        Description.text =ItemDescription;
        [cell addSubview:Description];

        //add sendOffer button
        UIButton *callSeller = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        callSeller.frame = CGRectMake(25, 8, 54, 45);
        [callSeller setTag:indexPath.row];

        [callSeller setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"makeOfferTable.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [callSeller setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"makeOfferTable.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

        [callSeller addTarget:self action:@selector(makeaOffer:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
        [cell addSubview:callSeller];

        UIView *myBackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
        myBackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"highlightCellBG.png"]];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = myBackView;
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

        //add newOffer sign (if new)
        if (!isRead){
            UIImageView *newIndocator = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(295, 0, 25, 25)];
            newIndocator.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newOfferIndicator.png"];
            [newIndocator setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
            [cell addSubview:newIndocator];
        }

    }

    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }


    return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        NSDictionary *object = [RequestArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"indePath.row = %d",indexPath.row);

        Seller_RequestDetailsViewController *infoView = [[Seller_RequestDetailsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Seller_RequestDetailsViewController" bundle:nil];

        NSString *OfferDate = [object valueForKey:@"Date"];

        NSTimeInterval TIMEinterval = [OfferDate intValue];
        NSDate* TIMEDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:TIMEinterval];
        NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [df setDateFormat:@"DD/MM/yyyy"];
        [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:2]]; //+0000

        infoView.date = [df stringFromDate:TIMEDate];


        infoView.itemName = [object valueForKey:@"ItemName"];
        infoView.modalName = [object valueForKey:@"ItemDegem"];
        infoView.buyerID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[object valueForKey:@"BuyerUserID"]];
        infoView.city = [object valueForKey:@"Region"];
        infoView.Offerdescription = [object valueForKey:@"ItemDescription"];
        BOOL isRead = [[object valueForKey:@"IsRead"]boolValue];

        infoView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
        [self presentModalViewController:infoView animated:YES];

        if (!isRead){
            [self markOfferAsRead:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[object valueForKey:@"ItemID"]]];
        }        

}
```

Comment: Why [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:2]? you should use [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0].

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your problem completely but I do see an error in the way you build the cells. After dequeueing the cell, you should only init the cell if it's nil NOT init and build the cell.

```
static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: SimpleTableIdentifier];

if(cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
}

// Now build the cell.
```

If you don't rebuild the cell every time, it will just reuse the cell that was originally built.

Comment: this is not my problem, if im not do it like its adding subviews one on one.. but let me focus the problem- my indexPath.row all ways change and this makes my cells data change (because im loading it from array by the index path.row)as well. i want my data in the cells to save in the same order it was loaded in the first time..

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that everything is with in this:

```
if(cell == nil) {
    //Your Code
}
```

What is happening is the tableview reuses cells. You are only changing the content `if(cell == nil)`.
What you need is to only create a new cell in side `if(cell == nil)`
and move the rest of your code out of that if statement